# getting a node's children that contains a certain tag - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const children = [...document.getElementsByClassName('profile')];
}
```

how do I do I access each children's child node that's an img tag?

I want to do something like

```
children.child.node('img').indexOf(e.target)

<div id="container">
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
    <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to get all `<img>` or only certain `<img>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for array manipulation, you can use the query string `.profile > img` to select `img`s which are direct children of a `.profile`:

```js
const imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.profile > img')];
console.log(imgs.length);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector `#container .profile img` to avoid the selection of undesired elements.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#container .profile > img')).forEach(img => console.log(img));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
<!-- This is an additionall container -->
<div id="container2">
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```